# Show that equivalence can be derived

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Show that the equivalence $$p \land \neg p \equiv F$$ can be derived using resolution together with
the fact that a conditional statement with a false hypothesis is true. [Hint: Let $q=r=F$ in resolution.]

Where do $q$ and $r$ fit in? And how do I use resolution to derive this equivalence?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding :

> "how do I use resolution to derive this equivalence ?"

I suppose that you have to use [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) to prove that the formula is *valid* (in fact, it is a *tautology*); this means that we can use *Resolution* to show that its negation is *unsatisfiable*.

First, we have to apply some equivalences to transform the negation of the original formula into a conjunction of [clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)) :

$\lnot [p ∧ ¬p \equiv F] \ $ is equiv to : $ \ 
\lnot ([(p ∧ ¬p) \to F] \land [F \to (p ∧ ¬p)])$ --- **(*)**

and again to :

$\lnot ([\lnot (p ∧ ¬p) \lor F] \land [\lnot F \lor (p ∧ ¬p)]) \ $

that is equiv to :

$\lnot [ (\lnot p \lor p \lor F) \land (T \lor p) \land (T \lor \lnot p)]$.

But $T \lor a \equiv T$, and thus we have :

$\lnot [ (\lnot p \lor p \lor F) \land T]$

and $T \land a \equiv a$, and finally we have :

> $\lnot (\lnot p \lor p \lor F)$.

Applying a last time De Morgan, we get :

> $p \land \lnot p \land T$.

Now we have the three clauses :

1) $p$

2) $\lnot p$

3) $T$;

applying the resolution rule to 1) and 2) we get the *empty clause*, and thus the formula is *unsatisfiable*.

So, its negation, i.e. the original formula, is *valid*.

---

*Side note*

Regarding the formula **(*)**, it is correct to say that we can apply "the fact that a conditional statement with a false hypothesis is true" to the RHS *conjunct* : $F \to (p ∧ ¬p)$ to conclude that it is *true*.

But what about the LHS one : $(p ∧ ¬p) \to F$ ? We cannot do the same, because we have *to prove* that $(p ∧ ¬p)$ is *false*...